# Push to code.google.com using Tower (Mac)

Tags: git, push, google-code, git-tower

I have made a copy of my repository and try to Push my code through Tower. However, that doesn't seem to work:

```
Pushing to https://mygoogleusername@code.google.com/p/hp-xxxxxx/
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see   
https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
```

I have followed Googles instructions, but something is wrong and I can't figure out what:

```
git clone https://mygoogleusername@code.google.com/p/hp-xxxxxx/ 

To push your changes, authenticate with your Google Account and your generated googlecode.com password.
```

#### In Tower, Edit URL Connection Info I have typed the following:

- Repository URL: https://mygoogleusername@code.google.com/p/hp-xxxxxx/
- Username: my google username
- Password: the auto generated password
- Proxy: Left empty
- SSL Certificate: Tried both checked and unchecked

#### Under Google Code User Preferences on the web -> Security I have tried both checked and unchecked with the following:

- Accept myusername@gmail.com Google Account password when using a Git or Mercurial client. To make sure your password is safe, always use the latest client from:

What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing your username from the URL?  I wonder if it's getting specified twice because you filled out the username section?

Comment: Tried it. Thing is that what I fill in to the username field automatically is added to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate using the .netrc method, i had the same problem but when i tried the .netrc method it worked without any issue.

Here are the steps:

```
echo machine code.google.com >> ~/.netrc
echo login <google_email_address> >> ~/.netrc
echo password <generated_password> >> ~/.netrc
chmod go= ~/.netrc
```

then instead of:

```
https://<username>@code.google.com/p/<project_name>/
```

use

```
https://code.google.com/p/<project_name>/
```

i.e without the username and it will work fine.

Note: You don't have to specify any username or password in Tower as when doing inter-server communication *nix automatically check the .netrc file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Tower only supports authentication via standards-compliant URL schemes.

Since Google Code does not actually use the username part of the URL when authenticating, you'll have to circumvent this like mentioned in the following post:
[Authenticating SourceTree with a Google Code project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344566/authenticating-sourcetree-with-a-google-code-project)

In short you'll have to create a .netrc file with your username and password - and remove the username portion from the URL completely in Tower.